# I can't make a post in nodejs that fills mysql createconnection

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need to make an app that allows the user to enter their database and connect to it. But don't know how to make that in the node api. The idea is that the user can input the host, user, port, password and database in the app and connect in the api, but everytime I try the mysql.createconnection doesn't receive the user's input.

```
    const dbData = {
    host: null,
    port: null,
    user: null,
    //dataPassword: null,
    database: null,
}

// CONEXÃO COM O BANCO
routes.post('/', (req, res)=> {
    dbData.host = req.body.host;
    dbData.port = req.body.port;
    dbData.user = req.body.user;
    //dbData.dataPassword = req.body.password;
    dbData.database = req.body.database;

    console.log(dbData);
});

const conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: dbData.host,
    port: dbData.port,
    user: dbData.user,
    //password: dbData.password,
    database: dbData.database,
});
```

I get an error with this code

```
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
  sqlState: '28000',
  fatal: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding how this code works. Here's an overview explained in the time-scale of the CPU world:

```
routes.post('/', (req, res)=> {
  // This code runs if and when a request to / is made
  // which as far as the CPU is concerned may as well be a billion years from now.
});

// This code runs right now, a billion years before that request is received.
const conn = mysql.createConnection({...});
```

In other words, you must move that connection request inside of the `post` function or it won't trigger at the correct time.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a beginner with programming. I've done what you said but how can I access conn from outside of that post?

Comment: What you're proposing here is rife with problems, almost too many to enumerate here. You'll need a global state variable you can manipulate, and additionally, this variable will persist *only* for the lifespan of the process as well as *only* for this process. If more than one is running this data is not shared. I'd *strongly* recommend saving this to the session and adding an Express handler that establishes the connection before doing any additional processing for it to have any hope of working.

Comment: Remember that HTTP is a *stateless protocol* and operates on a strict request/response model, where each request is considered independent of others. Processes get spawned, restarted, crash, and are replaced, plus might exist on many different physical or virtual servers. This is why you need to use a cookie-based session store to provide context to each incoming request.